# using ConnectivityManager without any activity

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

i have a class to control connection.

i have a `BroadcastReceiver` auto starter to start when booting the android

`BroadcastReceiver` calls a `service` . and `service` calls `Connectivity` class

```
boolean state=Connectivity.isConnected(this);
```

i get `Context` error in `Connectivity` class

also when i use `getApplicationContext();` to get the `Context`. i get `Null pointer` error
cause i do not have any activity working

i have only `services` and do not have any `activity`. application needs to work in background

how can i solve the problem
thanks

```
public class Connectivity {

    /**
     * Get the network info
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }
```

EDIT: using BroadcastReceiver Context solved my problem

Comment: You can use a `Service` to get a system service. Please post the stack trace of your "Context error".

Comment: "EDIT: using BroadcastReceiver Context solved my problem" Then you can post it as an answer to your own question.